# How to access the value of sbt variables like assemblyJarName?

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

in version 1.1.5.
For example, how to println it in build.sbt?
`println(assemblyJarName.value)`  won't work, turned out to be an err:
 `[error]      Did you mean assemblyPackageDependency / assemblyJarName ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `assemblyJarName` is defined in `build.sbt` like so

```
assemblyJarName in assembly := "hello.jar"
```

then try providing explicit task scope `assembly` when you call `value` as follows

```
println((assemblyJarName in assembly).value)
```

This is required because `assemblyJarName` setting is [scoped to a task](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scopes.html#Scoping+by+Task+axis) which we can see if we execute `inspect assemblyJarName`

```
inspect assemblyJarName
[info] No entry for key.
[info] Description:
[info]  name of the fat jar
[info] Delegates:
[info]  assemblyJarName
[info]  ThisBuild / assemblyJarName
[info]  Global / assemblyJarName
[info] Related:
[info]  assembly / assemblyJarName
[info]  assemblyPackageDependency / assemblyJarName
[info]  assemblyPackageScala / assemblyJarName
```

When we provide just the bare setting then its [default](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scopes.html#Referring+to+scopes+in+a+build+definition) scope is like so

```
inspect projFoo    /     Zero         /    Zero    /   assemblyJarName
           |              |                 |
        project      configuraition        task
```

but `assemblyJarName` does not exist in such scope

```
inspect assemblyJarName
[info] No entry for key.
```

however in `Related` section we see

```
[info] Related:
[info]  assembly / assemblyJarName
[info]  assemblyPackageDependency / assemblyJarName
[info]  assemblyPackageScala / assemblyJarName
```

which tells us `assemblyJarName` setting is scoped to the following three tasks

```
assembly
assemblyPackageDependency
assemblyPackageScala
```